# How to sum numbers saved as array in JavaScript with while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

Where is the mistake? I want to sum every number in the array. The alert says `NaN`.

```
var numbers = [10, 42, 5, 87, 61, 34, 99];
var i = 0; 
var e = 0;
while(i <= numbers.length) {
    e = e + numbers[i]; 
    i++;
}

alert(e);
```

Comment: while(i < numbers.length)

Comment: `[42]` is an array of length `1`. It only has an element at index `0`, not at index `1`.

Comment: *"Where is the mistake?"* Why do you think there is a mistake? Do you not get what you expect? What do you expect and what do you get? Please read [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in array length You are checking because array index starts with 0. In that way when doing:

```
i <= numbers.length
```

You are checking [0: 10, 1: 42, 2: 5, 3: 87, 4: 61, 5: 34, 6: 99, 7:???] because numbers length is 7. To solve it just do:

```
i < numbers.length
```

where You don't check non existing number in array.

Here is how we were thought in school:

```
//main code//
var numbers = [10, 42, 5, 87, 61, 34, 99];
var result = sumIntArray(numbers);
//end of main code//

function sumIntArray(array){
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].isInteger()) {
            result += array[i];
        } else {
            if (i === 0) {
                alert("1st object in array is not number, will skip...");
            } 
            else if (i === 1) {
                alert("2nd object in array is not number, will skip...");
            }  
            else if (i === 2){
                alert("3rd object in array is not number, will skip...");
            }    
            else {
                alert((i+1).toString() + "th object in array is not number, will skip...");
            }
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

The **for** loop adds this i++ You make in a while loop and makes code a bit more clear. 
No need for declaring **i** in main code :)

1. Always make functions to simplify main code.
2. Make function that will never make mistake even if somebody wants to break **The logic**.

Although don't make school break Your creativity, Your code is great! :)

Answer (score 4):

This line is the reason:

```
while(i <= numbers.length) {
```

Arrays are 0 index so you can go from index 0 (inclusive) until `numbers.length` (*exclusive*). You are going beyond that limit, causing you to access an element that isn't defined at the given index. You must do this instead:

```
while(i < numbers.length) {
```

Answer (score 3):

**Alternatively** using the **ES2015 syntax** you can do it like this.

```
let numbers = [10, 42, 5, 87, 61, 34, 99];
let sum = numbers.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

You can read about `Array.prototype.reduce(accumulator, element, callback, startingValue)` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: But they asked what was wrong with their code... not for an alternative. Solve the problem first *then* offer an alternative.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I will do that now.

Comment: Its a good answer and helps future readers. Please don't drop ES syntax.

Comment: @user2330678 Agreed, but solve the problem at hand first. I agree the ES6 syntax is preferred but answer the question first.

Comment: I just emphasised it is an alternative, the other answers give a hint of what was wrong in the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong, just use < insteead of <=

```
while(i < numbers.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you can improve this. The first is that you want to change your condition to `i < numbers.length`, not `i <= numbers.length`. As you've written it, the last number will never be counted.

Another way you can improve this is using the `+=` notation -- there's no need to write `e = e + numbers[i]` when you can write `e += numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could íterate from the end of the array with a [post increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) and a check for truthyness in the [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) condition.

Inside just add the item.

```js
var numbers = [10, 42, 5, 87, 61, 34, 99],
    i = numbers.length,
    e = 0;

while (i--) {
    e += numbers[i]; 
}

console.log(e);
```