# Find perimeter of a polygon

Tags: javascript, arrays

The description of the problem is given in comment at the top of the code.
The output I get is NaN instead of an integer value of perimeter

```
/*
 * Implement a Polygon class with the following properties:
 * 1. A constructor that takes an array of integer side lengths.
 * 2. A 'perimeter' method that returns the sum of the Polygon's side lengths.
 */
class Polygon
{
    constructor(sides)
    {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    perimeter()
    {
        var per = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides.length; i++)
        {
            per += this.sides[i];
        }
        return per;
    }
}
```

This piece of code runs the above code:

```
const rectangle = new Polygon([10, 20, 10, 20]);
const square = new Polygon([10, 10, 10, 10]);
const pentagon = new Polygon([10, 20, 30, 40, 43]);

console.log(rectangle.perimeter());
console.log(square.perimeter());
console.log(pentagon.perimeter());
```

Comment: You're iterating too far: `i <= this.sides.length` should be  `i < this.sides.length`.  I vote to close as a typo.

Comment: Change `<=` to `<` in your loop :)

Comment: indexes in arrays start from 0, and goes until N - 1. Thus, as others stated you should replace `<=` with `<`

Comment: Is also duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729085/how-to-sum-numbers-saved-as-array-in-javascript-with-while-loop) together with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of your `for` loop goes 1 past the end of the array.

`for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides.length; i++)`

The array of size `length` will have `length - 1` as the last index.  To fix this, use:

`for (var i = 0; i < this.sides.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Change `<=` for `<` so you don't go over the bounds of your `sides` array:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= this.sides.length; i++)
```

for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.sides.length; i++)
```

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum your sides:

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(sides) {
      this.sides = sides;
  }

  perimeter() {
    return this.sides.reduce((sum, side) => sum + side, 0);
  }
}

const rectangle = new Polygon([10, 20, 10, 20]);
const square = new Polygon([10, 10, 10, 10]);
const pentagon = new Polygon([10, 20, 30, 40, 43]);

console.log(rectangle.perimeter());
console.log(square.perimeter());
console.log(pentagon.perimeter());
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, the problem is that the `i` will go one off the end of the array, and that'll give you problems. This is an illustration of a problem which can arise from using for loops to iterate over an array; `i` is only incidentally related to the array over which you're iterating, and it's easy enough to have problems where the relationship that we *think* we're creating between `i` and the array is not quite the same as that which we create in the code.

For this reason, I'd recommend using something like `reduce`. You might also use `forEach` and keep track of the sum, but `reduce` is by far the best option for a sum as it's designed to take something iterable and produce a single value.

Here's how that might look:

```js
class Polygon
{
    constructor(sides)
    {
        this.sides = sides;
    }

    perimeter()
    {
      return this.sides.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    }
}

const rectangle = new Polygon([10, 20, 10, 20]);
const square = new Polygon([10, 10, 10, 10]);
const pentagon = new Polygon([10, 20, 30, 40, 43]);

console.log(rectangle.perimeter());
console.log(square.perimeter());
console.log(pentagon.perimeter());
```